# Neo4j Cypher ToInt function not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j v 2.3.0. This *cypher* query returns zeros for LOS. `DaysOfCare` is a string.

```
MATCH x-[rr]-(a:Discharge)-[r]-(b:Dx)
WHERE b.ICD9='25000'
RETURN
  x.ICD9,
  x.DIAG_DESC,
  type(r),
  count(x.DIAG_DESC) as Ct,    
  sum(TOINT(x.DaysOfCare)) as LOS
ORDER BY Ct DESC LIMIT 250
```

What's wrong here?

Has `ToInt` not yet been added as planned? Is this a bug or am I using the combination of `Sum` and `ToInt` incorrectly?

Comment: Do you mean Neo4j version 2.2?  I don't believe that 2.3.x exists yet

Comment: @BrianUnderwood - Neo4j 2.3.0-M01 milestone candidate is available for download. I assume the OP is using that.

Comment: Oh, wow, that was quick!  Thanks ceej

Comment: Yes, I'm using the newly released Neo4j 2.3.0-M01.  Did they leave ToInt out?

Answer (score 1):

The `TOINT` function has been part of Cypher for a while.  What if you tried to change this line:

```
sum(TOINT(x.DaysOfCare)) as LOS
```

To this:

```
collect(x.DaysOfCare) as LOS
```

That might give you some insight as to why it's not working.

Comment: I'm adding up numbers.  Collect did not work in the context suggested.

Comment: I know you're adding up numbers and that that's not what collect gives you, but what does collect give you?  If you look at the result of collect you can then try applying toint to those values to see why the some of them might be zero.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you.  My query returns a set of rows and the LOS column has no content when I use collect(x.DaysOfCare) as LOS or variations such as sum(toInt(collect(x.DaysOfCare)) as LOS.  I considered that there may be a NULL in my aggregated set, so I tried sum(ToInt(case when x.DaysOfCare is null then '0' else x.DaysOfCare end)) as LOS but this did not work either.

Comment: Oh, well there you have it.  If collect is return an empty array then the sum function is summing over an empty array and thus it's returning 0.  So it's not a problem with toint.  I suspect it's a problem with matching the right nodes.

Comment: Actually, looking at it now the answer seems obvious.  You're summing over a property on `x` but at the same time you're trying to return properties on `x` in the same result.  When you use an aggregation function Neo4j automatically aggregates on whatever non-aggregation columns are in the `RETURN`

Answer (score 0):

The query in the original question was not summing the correct data.  This query produces the anticipated results:

```
MATCH x-[rr]-(a:Discharge)-[r]-(b:Dx) where b.ICD9='25000'  RETURN x.ICD9,x.DIAG_DESC,type(r),count(x.DIAG_DESC) as Ct,sum(ToInt(a.DaysOfCare)) as LOS order by Ct desc LIMIT 250
```

The a-node set is hospital discharges, which contains metadata, including the days of care.  The query seeks a target diagnosis (25000 = diabetes mellitus) and then in the x nodes, other discharge diagnoses.  The associated diagnoses are not random; certain conditions are clustered.  First few lines of output are:

[image]

Clearly, ToInt is working correctly ... it's the user who was messed up.